# How do I call a C library from asm?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, nasm, linker-errors

I am trying to call a function included in the C standard library (namely, `puts`, but it shouldn't matter) from an assembly program. Creating an object file from the assembly code works but the linking stage does not. As I am a complete beginner on assembly programming I am basically unable to even interpret the error messages. Any help or explanation on what is going wrong would be really appreciated!

I loosely followed this [tutorial](https://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/nasmtutorial/), but having code identical to it still doesn't work. My expectation is that I would get an executable file, but in reality I don't get past the linking stage.

My code: (`file.asm`)

```
global  main
extern  puts

section .text
main:
    mov rdi, msg
    call    puts
    ret

msg:
    db  "Hello, world!", 0
```

Commands and errors:

```
$ nasm -felf64 file.asm 
$ gcc file.o
/usr/bin/ld: warning: file.o: missing .note.GNU-stack section implies executable stack
/usr/bin/ld: NOTE: This behaviour is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of the linker
/usr/bin/ld: file.o: warning: relocation in read-only section `.text'
/usr/bin/ld: file.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `puts@@GLIBC_2.2.5' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIE
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

I have tried searching for help on this on the internet but I see no difference from what I am already doing.

Comment: I see `recompile with -fPIE` in the suggestions / warnings from the linker, have you tried this?

Comment: Did you try running it with `nasm -felf64 file.asm && gcc file.o && ./a.out`?

Comment: @Pac0 Yes, it didn't change a thing.

Comment: @AleksaMajkic I did now, but the linking errors still occurred. I also see no reason for it to differ from running the commands separately, if I know my shell right.

Comment: From asking the same question on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/asm/comments/1afi6nr/linker_error_on_calling_c_libraries_from_asm/) it appears the issue was with "Position Independent Executables" - PIEs (i.e. ASLR). My asm code seems to be incompatible with it. Using GCC with `-no-pie` disables PIE and thus things begin to work!

Comment: @Oka It appears to! It was also quite a bit more extensive than the Reddit answer I got which is nice :)

Comment: lobal? ... _**lobal**_?  what _**on earth**_ is this?

Comment: @MikeNakis A typo from copying and pasting, it of course should read `global`.